# Devexpress: application is in hold mode at breakpoint in DevExpress Events

Tags: devexpress, native-code

everytime when my code hits a breakpoint in an Devexpress Event the applcation stops with a new windows.

Application is in hold mode

Your app has stopped, but no code supported by the selected debug engine is currently running (e.g. only native code is running)

What I think is that the debugger didnt know the code of DEvexpress?!

what can I do?

regards Jürgen

I change the debugging settings, native code on/off